# Requiring components in Angular 2, top down or bottom up?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I've been reading up on Angular 2 and its components etc. However, I have one big question that I have been unable to answer as of yet. Basically, I have one big issue with Angular 1 and which is the top down require pattern in directives/components. It does not seem right that components should depend on other components outside themselves, instead they should requiring components inside themselves. I am wondering if Angular 2 is reversing the require order of components (i.e. allowing components to require from below and not above)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If a component or directives refers to another component or directive from its code or from its template it needs to import it (code) and if used in the template, also be added to the `directives: [...]` list.

I think this is what you're asking for. If a component used another component it needs to import it, but it doesn't have to know in any way by what components it used itself.